# How to optimize initial loading speed of Angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

At this moment, my Angular 13 app has been minimized in terms of size. Gzip applied, the data transfer is reduced to 720kb and now the Lighthouse asks me to "Minimize main thread work". I am not sure how that is supposed to work with Angular, so I would just post the result of it here.

Result of "Minimize main thread work":
[image]

Result of "Reduce JavaScript execution time":
[image]

I guess I am supposed to reduce the polyfills.js. I have searched around on the Internet and didn't find a meaningful solution for that.

So far I have removed all the components and most libraries that I am not currently using, have tried SSR with Angular Universal but then found it doesn't fit as I need to make some DOM manipulation on my home page. At this moment all I need is to speed up my initial home page loading speed, so I just ignored it. Gzip is applied through a NodeJS middleware that runs an express server to send the content from /dist to the internet, so I assume the main reason for the loading being slow is still on js part.

Please let me know if there's any way I can sort this out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "classic" is using [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading

Answer (score 0):

The result of "Reduce JavaScript execution time" from the Lighthouse report is a bit misleading. Your polyfills includes Zone.js which patches most of the [standard APIs](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/STANDARD-APIS.md) and therefore almost all of the JavaScript execution from your application is assigned to it. In order to reduce the execution time I'd suggest that you use the Chrome DevTools performance tab to [analyze the runtime performance](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) and optimize potential bottlenecks.

As you're polling data the UI might be updated quite frequently, so it could also help to avoid unnecessary change detection by leveraging the [OnPush strategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy).
You can utilize the [Angular DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh) to investigate how costly & frequent a certain component's change detection is.

Comment: Just wondering, would the OnPush strategy still allow the change detector to function when I manually trigger it by calling markForCheck()? For now, mostly I am using it as the view doesn't update itself in most cases.

Comment: Looked at the runtime performance, it shows 4 seconds' scripting, 1.5 seconds' rendering and 18 seconds doing nothing. Is it a sign I should somehow optimize the scripting part?

Comment: When the OnPush strategy is used, change detection is only triggered when inputs change or events are emitted. In all other cases you can call `markForCheck()` or `detectChanges()` to manually trigger it.

Yes, you should optimize the scripting part. One thing I noticed is, that you have lots of [forced reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a). Are you doing some direct DOM manipulation?